# A recursion error I can't figure out

Tags: python, recursion, kivy

I am trying to make a scatter plane layout behave how I want it to but when I try to zoom out past a certain point I get the error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" I can't figure out why the recursion happens, tho by trial and error I have found out where it happens (it is marked in the code)

here is the traceback: http://pastebin.com/i2z8SXgc

```
class Controller(ScatterPlaneLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_transform(self, instance, value):
        win = self.get_parent_window().size
        this = self.bbox[1]

        if win[0] > this[0] and win[1] > this[1]:
            if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 0
            if self.y < 0:
                self.y = 0
            if this[0] + self.x > win[0]:
                self.set_right(win[0])
            if this[1] + self.y > win[1]:
                self.set_top(win[1])

        else:
            if self.x > 0:
                self.x = 0
            if self.y > 0:
                self.y = 0
               #This is the part that causes the error
            if this[0] + self.x < win[0]:
                self.x = win[0] - this[0]
               #end of error
            if this[1] + self.y < win[1]:
                self.set_top(win[1])
```

Comment: it might be useful to also put the stack trace (the part that gets repeated)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines, especially [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Give us sample input and output (both desired and what you get with your coding attempt).  Since you know where the problem lies, it would help if you told us.

Comment: Oops I thought I had put that in, well it is now, the problem is that when I try to zoom out past a certain point it crashes also the error is marked in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks to be causing the error is the code `self.x = win[0] - this[0]` calling the function on_transform, passing the first if and calling itself all over again and again.

You *may* want to check that.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot, thank you I've been in that ditch for weeks, and looking over my own code I obviously solved that before